# Probability Mass fuction for scratch ticket

Tags: probability, statistics, probability-distributions

A lottery ticket has 4 squares, each with either a star or an X. The printer printing these tickets has a 20% chance of printing a star per individual square. If the amount paid per star is as follows:

1 star: $2

2 stars: $4

3 stars: $10

4 stars: $50

What is the probability mass function for the amount that is paid out for a ticket?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint:** Let $Y$ be the random variable equal to the number of stars printed. $Y$ follows the binomial distribution, which has PMF $$p_{Y}(y) = \binom{4}{y}p^y(1-p)^{4-y}$$

with $p = 0.2$ since there is a $20\%$ chance of printing a star in an individual square.

Now for each possible value of $Y$, multiply it by the amount paid per star to get the PMF of the amount paid out.

Comment: So if each ticket costs $2 what would the PMF for the amount paid out be?

Comment: Technically the amount paid out is the same. But if you are looking for the profit, just subtract \$2 from the four cases given. 1 star has \$0 profit (\$2 is paid out, but you spent \$2), 2 stars has \$2 profit, 3 stars has \$8 profit, and 4 stars has \$48 profit.

Comment: Also 0 stars has -\$2 profit.